# How can I fit an image inside a square shape in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/homepage.jpg',
                        ),
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

There is another part of the image above that remains below. I want to fit the whole photo into a container with a height and width of 200.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you wanted:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/timepass.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: No. The image only fills half of the card.

Comment: have you tried fit or contain?

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed.

Comment: can you give me the code of your whole class?

Comment: and also this photo that you want to use

Comment: https://photo-cdn2.icons8.com/8Tu96h1fqlvy9irZQv1GLPPqQeEqvSda449Uf_h9NPg/rs:fit:576:864/czM6Ly9pY29uczgu/bW9vc2UtcHJvZC5h/c3NldHMvYXNzZXRz/L3NhdGEvb3JpZ2lu/YWwvMjQzLzA2Mjk0/NmZmLTAxMDctNDRj/YS04ZjliLTE2MjNl/MGFmZDczOC5qcGc.webp

Comment: Check it now I've edited your code

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Image.network(
         'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/0900/7035/products/kiss-cut-stickers-5.5x5.5-default-606a33ae77a7e_grande.jpg?v=1617572787',),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```